# Adding Dependencies to Swift Command Line Tool

Tags: swift, command-line, dependencies, shared-libraries

I have tried to add a time tracking app with library to my swift 4 command line tool in Xcode 9. I have tried using cocopods and using the instructions the author of the code left, but I cannot make it work. Whenever I try and include it by saying:

```
import Stopwatch
```

It gives the error saying "No such module 'stopwatch'"
 If anyone could give me some steps to install it, it would be greatly appreciated.

I am getting the time tracker from https://github.com/matejkosiarcik/Stopwatch#build-from-source-1

The instructions have not helped.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods by default adds your dependencies as frameworks, which is not supported in a command line tool as you are describing. Make sure you comment-out the following line in your Podfile:

```
...
# use_frameworks!
...
```

The problem is that you can not integrate pods written in swift in this way, because they require you use `use_frameworks!`

Comment: Thank you, but does that mean I will not be able to add it too my command line tool? Also, which bit do I then need to add too my pod file?